# Simlification using boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

What is the simplest form of `A'B'C' + A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C'` ? I've tried doing it using both K-map and Boolean algebra rules but they gave me different answers!

Comment: Please post your working for the two methods. I guarantee you made an error in at least one of them.

Comment: What's the simplest form using and,or,not only??

Comment: See my answer, the last line in the first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form that I can find is

```
A'B'C' + A'B'C + A'BC' + AB'C'
A'B'(C'+C) + (A'B + AB')C'
A'B'(1) + (A'B + AB')C'
A'B' + (A'B + AB')C'
```

which is

```
A'B' + (A XOR B)C'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
A'B' + A'C' + B'C'
```

or

```
A'B' + (AB)'C'
```

The Karnaugh map:

```
             bc
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   0  | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
a     +---+---+---+---+
   1  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```